# work around for javascript php login system

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

Im building a login/register system using javascript to show particular divs for the system e.g

1st div = menu option to either login or register

2nd div = depending on what was clicked (login or register) shows login form or register form

3rd div = shows when user has successfully registered/logged in

the script looks like this:

html:

```
<article id="container">
            <div id="load-new" class="game_menu">
                <h1>LOAD/NEW</h1>
                <button id="new_but" type="button">New Game</button>
                <button id="load_but" type="button">Load Game</button>
            </div>
            <div id="reg" class="game_menu">
                <h1>REGISTER</h1>
                <form name="register" method="post" action="">
                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname">Your username</label>
                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail"> Your email</label>
                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="domain@mydomain.com"/>
                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd">Your password </label>
                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password"/>
                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd">Please confirm your password </label>
                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password"/>
                    <button id="reg_submit" type="button">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="login" class="game_menu">
                <h1>LOGIN</h1>
                <form name="login" method="post" action="">
                    <label for="username" id="username_label">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
                    <label for="password" id="password_label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""/>
                    <button id="login_submit" type="button">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="access" class="game_menu">
                <h1>ACCESS</h1>
                <button id="login_but" type="button">Login</button>
                <button id="reg_but" type="button">Register</button>
            </div>
            <canvas id="TBG" width="640" height="416">
                Please use a more up to date browser
            </canvas>
```

the javascript looks like this

main.js:

```
    //----------Login/Register Gui --------------
$('#load-new').hide();
$('#reg').hide();
$('#login').hide();

//create new instance of gui class
var ui = new Gui();

//if login_but is clicked do ui.login function
$('#login_but').click(ui.login);
//if reg_but is clicked do ui.register function
$('#reg_but').click(ui.register);
//if login_sumbit button is clicked do ui.login_ajax function
$("#login_submit").click(ui.login_ajax);

$("#reg_submit").click(ui.register_ajax);
```

gui.js:

```
function Gui (){


var valid = 'true';
var invalid = 'false';

//hide access div, show login div
this.login = function()
{
    $('#access').hide();
    $('#login').show();
};

//hide access div, show register div
this.register = function()
{
    $('#access').hide();
    $('#reg').show();
};

//function to send login data to php script login.php
this.login_ajax = function()
{
    //username user inputted
    var username = $("#username").val();
    //password user inputted
    var password = $("#password").val();

    //inputted data made into JSON string
    var dataString = {"reg":invalid, "login":valid,  "username":username , 
    "password":password};

    //AJAX Request to login.php
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"PHP/class.ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(success) {
            alert("Your are logged in");
            if(success == 'true'){
            $('#login').hide();
            $('#load-new').show();
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("ERROR in AJAX");
        }

    });
};

this.register_ajax = function()
{
    var username_signup = $("#usernamesignup").val();
    var email_signup = $("#emailsignup").val();
    var password_signup = $("#passwordsignup").val();
    var password_signup_confirm = $('#passwordsignup_confirm').val();

    var dataString = {"reg":valid, "login":invalid, "username_signup":username_signup,
                                "email_signup":email_signup,
 "password_signup":password_signup, "password_signup_confirm":password_signup_confirm};

    $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
        url:"PHP/class.ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(success) {
            alert("You are registered");
            if(success == 'true'){
                $('#reg').hide();
                $()
                $('#load-new').show();
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("ERROR in AJAX");
        }
    });
}
```

}

i use ajax to send requests to php scripts to process login or register.
the script that the ajax requests is simple a go between so i can select specific functions in either the login php or register php.

i would like to have an are in my html to show if a user is logged in or not a bit like the are in the top right on the runescape website : [here](http://www.runescape.com).

now i tried this php in my header.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$is_logged_in = '<div id = "user_box">Welcome '.$_POST['username'].'</div>';
}
else
 {
$is_logged_in = '<div id = "welcome_box">Welcome friend!</div>';
}
```

but obviously this wouldnt work because the page doesnt refresh where im using javascript to show different parts of the menu.

MY QUESTION:

What would be the most pratical way to achieving this effect with the javascript/php system i have in place?

Would i use javascript to hide/show divs like i have with the menu divs? or is there a function i can use to refresh the page without it sending me back to the first menu div?

Thanks for your time
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are only sending back one value from the php scripts that you are calling using ajax, you are only using `true` for a successful login or registration.

What you could do, is modify these scripts to return multiple values. So apart from the `true` value for a successful login, you also send the username and then in your javascript you use that username to build a html block to show in the top area where you want to show the username.

You are already using json, so you only have to generate an array with return values in your php script and use `echo json_encode($your_return_values);` to send it to your javascript `success` variable.

By the way, you can use jquery / javascript to replace and build whole sections of your html, you don't need to put everything in at the start just to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly your wanting to indicate to the user that they are logged in without reloading the page and by displaying a div in the top right corner.

That being the case you could create a hidden div with an absolute top right position which would be something like:

```
<div id="welcome" style="display:none; postion:absolute; top:0; float:right;">...</div>
```

In the 'success:' portion of the ajax request above, add a call to a new js function that makes a separate ajax request to retrieve a json object containing the logged in users display name and any other information that you want to show.  Using that json data you could then populate 'welcome' div accordingly and change it's display to block.